# IF Statement Multi Line Response

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code which was programmed by a friend for a quiz system we have been working on. Depending on the student's score a message is displayed

I now need to change the code so that the message from the IF is formatted onto several lines. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction. Not experienced in JavaScript at all.

```
   if(studentScore <= 150)
  var phrase = "Well done, you have achieved level bronze";
else if(studentScore <= 300)
  var phrase = "Well done, you have achieved level silver";
else if(studentScore <= 450)
  var phrase = "Well done, you have achieved level gold";
else if(studentScore <= 600)
  var phrase = "Well done, you have achieved level platinum";
else if(studentScore <= 800)
  var phrase = "Well done, you have achieved level double platinum";
else
  var phrase = "Well done, you have achieved level triple platinum";

  config = {
     elName: 'h2',
     text: phrase
  };
```

The quiz is created in Articulate, I have been working on the output report in the report.html file. The full contents of this file is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
    <title>Results</title>
    <style>

    body {
      font-family: arial;
      text-align: center;
      font-size:10pt;
    }

    table {
      border: 1px outset grey;
    }

    td, th {
      border: 1px inset grey;
    }

    table.summary {
      width: 600px;
    }

    table.questions  {
      width: 100%;
    }

    td {
      width: 12.5%;
    }

    th, h3 {
      font-size:12pt;
    }

    h1, h2 {
      font-size:14pt;
    }

    .correct {
      color: #008800;
    }

    .incorrect {
      color: #880000;
    }

    .neutral {
      color: #000088;
    }

    .question {
      text-align: left;
      width: 46.25%;
    }

    .number {
      font-size:10pt;
      width: 3.75%;
    }

    .datetime {
      font-size:10pt;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

  </style>
    <script>

var strings = {}
try {
  strings = {
    months: [
      __MONTH_JAN__,
      __MONTH_FEB__,
      __MONTH_MAR__,
      __MONTH_APR__,
      __MONTH_MAY__,
      __MONTH_JUN__,
      __MONTH_JUL__,
      __MONTH_AUG__,
      __MONTH_SEP__,
      __MONTH_OCT__,
      __MONTH_NOV__,
      __MONTH_DEC__
    ],
    dateTime: __DATE_TIME__,
    studentScore: __STUDENT_SCORE__,
    passScore: __PASSING_SCORE__,
    courseResult: __COURSE_RESULT__,
    question: __QUESTION__,
    correctAnswer: __CORRECT_ANS__,
    quizResult: __QUIZ_RESULT__,
    studentAnswer: __STUDENT_ANS__,
    pointsAwarded: __POINTS_AWARD__,
    neutral: __NEUTRAL__,
    correct: __CORRECT__,
    incorrect: __INCORRECT__
  };
} catch (e) {
  strings = {
    months: [
      'January',
      'February',
      'March',
      'April',
      'May',
      'June',
      'July',
      'August',
      'September',
      'October',
      'November',
      'December'
    ],
    dateTime: 'Date / Time',
    studentScore: 'Student Score',
    passingScore: 'Passing Score',
    courseResult: 'Result',

    question: 'Question',
    correctAnswer: 'Correct Answer',
    quizResult: 'Result',
    studentAnswer: 'Student Answer',
    pointsAwarded: 'Points Awarded',
    neutral: 'Neutral',
    correct: 'Correct',
    incorrect: 'Incorrect'
  };
}

function setupPrint(data) {
  var courseResults = data.g_oContentResults,
      quizzes = data.g_listQuizzes,
      printOptions = data.g_oPrintOptions,
      quizOrder = printOptions.arrQuizzes,
      mainQuiz = quizzes[printOptions.strMainQuizId];

  // turn date back into date object
  courseResults.dtmFinished = new Date(JSON.parse(courseResults.dtmFinished));

  function displayHeader() {
    var header = document.getElementById('header'),
        userName = printOptions.strName
        config = {
          elName: 'div',
          children: [
            { elName: 'h1', text: mainQuiz.strQuizName},
            { elName: 'h2', text: userName, enabled: userName != null && userName.length > 0},
          ]
        };

    header.appendChild(createElFromDef(config));
  }

  function displayCourseSummary() {
    var survey = printOptions.bSurvey,
        showUserScore = !survey && printOptions.bShowUserScore,
        showPassingScore = !survey && printOptions.bShowPassingScore,
        showPassFail = !survey && printOptions.bShowShowPassFail,
        studentScore = (Number(mainQuiz.nPtScore) * 14),
        passingScore = Number(mainQuiz.nPassingScore),
        courseResult = (studentScore >= passingScore) ? 'Pass' : 'Fail',
        currentDateTime = formatDate(courseResults.dtmFinished),
        courseSummary = document.getElementById('courseSummary'),
        config = {
          elName: 'table',
          attrs: [{ name: 'class', value: 'summary' }, { name: 'align', value: 'center' }],
          children: [
            { elName: 'tr',
              children: [
                { elName: 'th', text: strings.dateTime},
                { elName: 'th', text: strings.studentScore, enabled: showUserScore},
                { elName: 'th', text: strings.passingScore, enabled: showPassingScore},
                { elName: 'th', text: strings.courseResult, enabled: showPassFail}
            ]},
            { elName: 'tr',
              children: [
                { elName: 'td',
                  children: [
                    { elName: 'p', attrs: [{ name: 'class', value:'datetime' }], text: currentDateTime.date },
                    { elName: 'p', attrs: [{ name: 'class', value:'datetime' }], text: currentDateTime.time }
                ]},
                { elName: 'td', text: studentScore, enabled: showUserScore },
                { elName: 'td', text: passingScore, enabled: showPassingScore },
                { elName: 'td', text: courseResult, enabled: showPassFail }
            ]}
          ]
        };

    courseSummary.appendChild(createElFromDef(config));

    if(studentScore <= 150)
      var phrase = "Well done, you have achieved level bronze";
    else if(studentScore <= 300)
      var phrase = "Well done, you have achieved level silver";
    else if(studentScore <= 450)
      var phrase = "Well done, you have achieved level gold";
    else if(studentScore <= 600)
      var phrase = "Well done, you have achieved level platinum";
    else if(studentScore <= 800)
      var phrase = "Well done, you have achieved level double platinum";
    else
      var phrase = "Well done, you have achieved level triple platinum";

      config = {
         elName: 'h2',
         text: phrase
      };

    courseSummary.appendChild(createElFromDef(config));
  }

  function displayQuizResults() {
    for (var i = 0; i < quizOrder.length; i++) {
      var quizId = quizOrder[i];
      displayQuizResult(quizId);
    }
  };

  function displayQuizResult(quizId) {
    var i, resultsTable;
        quiz = quizzes[quizId],
        questionOrder = getQuestionOrder(quiz),
        quizDiv = createQuizDiv(quiz),
        quizReview = document.getElementById('quizReview');


    quizReview.appendChild(quizDiv);
    resultsTable = document.getElementById([ 'results-', quizId ].join(''));

    for (i = 0; i < questionOrder.length; i++) {
      var config = getQuestionConfig(quiz, questionOrder[i]);
      resultsTable.appendChild(createElFromDef(config));
    }
  };

  function createQuizDiv(quiz) {
    var survey = printOptions.bSurvey;

    return createElFromDef({
      elName: 'div',
      children: [
        { elName: 'h3', text: quiz.strQuizName },
        { elName: 'table',
          attrs: [
            { name: 'class', value: 'questions' },
            { name: 'id', value: [ 'results-', quiz.strQuizId ].join('') }
          ],
          children: [
            { elName: 'tr', children: [
              { elName: 'th', text: '#' },
              { elName: 'th', text: strings.question },
              { elName: 'th', text: strings.correctAnswer, enabled: !survey},
              { elName: 'th', text: strings.studentAnswer },
              { elName: 'th', text: strings.quizResult, enabled: !survey },
              { elName: 'th', text: strings.pointsAwarded, enabled: !survey }
          ]}
        ]}
      ]
    });
  };

  function createElFromDef(elDef) {
    if (elDef.enabled === false) {
      return null;
    }

    var el = createAndInitElement(elDef.elName, elDef.attrs, elDef.text);

    if (elDef.children != null) {
      for (var i = 0; i < elDef.children.length; i++) {
        currEl = createElFromDef(elDef.children[i]);
        if (currEl != null) {
          el.appendChild(currEl);
        }
      }
    }

    return el;
  };

  function createAndInitElement(elementName, attrs, text) {
    var el = document.createElement(elementName);

    if (attrs != null) {
      for (var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
        var attr = attrs[i];
        el.setAttribute(attr.name, attr.value);
      }
    }

    if (text != null) {
      el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    }

    return el;
  };

  function getQuestionOrder(quiz) {
    var i, j,
        questionOrder = [],
        questions = quiz.arrQuestions;

    if (questions != null && questions.length > 0)  {
      // reset
      if (questions[0].found) {
        for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
          questions[i].found = false;
        }
      }

      for (i = questions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var index = -1,
            maxQuestionNum = -1,
            currQuestionNum;

        for (j = 0; j < questions.length; j++) {
          currQuestionNum = Number(questions[j].nQuestionNumber);
          if (!questions[j].found && currQuestionNum > maxQuestionNum) {
            maxQuestionNum = currQuestionNum;
            if (index >= 0) {
              questions[index].found = false;
            }
            questions[j].found = true;
            index = j;
          }
        }
        questionOrder[i] = index;
      }
    }

    return questionOrder;
  }

  function getQuestionConfig(quiz, questionIdx) {
    var questions = quiz.arrQuestions,
        question = questions[questionIdx],
        survey = printOptions.bSurvey;

    return {
      elName: 'tr',
      children: [
        { elName: 'td', attrs: [{ name: 'class', value: 'number'}], text: question.nQuestionNumber },
        { elName: 'td', attrs: [{ name: 'class', value: 'question'}], text: question.strDescription },
        { elName: 'td', text: formatResponse(question.strCorrectResponse), enabled: !survey},
        { elName: 'td', text: formatResponse(question.strUserResponse) },
        { elName: 'td', attrs: [{ name: 'class', value: question.strStatus}], text: strings[question.strStatus], enabled: !survey },
        { elName: 'td', text: question.nPoints, enabled: !survey }
      ]
    };
  };

  function formatResponse(response) {
    return (response != null) ? response.replace(/\|#\|/g, ', ') : '&nbsp';
  }

  function formatDate(dtm) {
    var hours = dtm.getHours(),
        period = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am',
        minutes = dtm.getMinutes().toString(),
        month = strings.months[dtm.getMonth()],
        date = dtm.getDate(),
        year = dtm.getFullYear();

    while (minutes.length < 2) {
      minutes = '0' + minutes;
    }

    if (hours > 12) {
      hours -= 12;
    }

    return {
      date: [ month, ' ', date, ', ', year ].join(''),
      time: [ hours, ':', minutes, ' ', period ].join('')
    }
  };

  function init() {
    displayHeader();
    displayCourseSummary();
    if (printOptions.bShowQuizReview) {
      displayQuizResults();
    }
  }
  init();
}

// use post message to allow this to work locally and in 360 review
window.opener.postMessage('getQuizData', '*');

window.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
  setupPrint(JSON.parse(e.data));
}, false);

</script> </head>
  <body>
    <h1><i>Writing Certificate </i></h1>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="courseSummary"></div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div id="quizReview"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Update: 
Following on from feedback I have amended my code to the following (Removal of unneeded Var and inclusion on \n)

```
     courseSummary.appendChild(createElFromDef(config));
    var phrase;
    if(studentScore <= 150)
     phrase = ('line one\nline two');
    else if(studentScore <= 300)
     phrase = ('line one\nline two');
    else if(studentScore <= 450)
     phrase = ('line one\nline two');
    else if(studentScore <= 600)
     phrase = ('line one\nline two');
    else if(studentScore <= 800)
     phrase = ('line one\nline two');
    else
     phrase = ('line one\nline two');

      config = {
         elName: 'h2',
         text: phrase
      };

    courseSummary.appendChild(createElFromDef(config));
  }
```

this has tided the variables and introduced the /n to break the lines, however my output is still on a single line.

e.g.

line one line two

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzexe.png)

Would anyone be able to offer anymore guidance - Many thanks

---

Update:

Just attempted the < br > solution with no success

output simply shows line one < br >line two               (no spaces in code)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKWBa.png)

code as follows

```
    courseSummary.appendChild(createElFromDef(config));
    var phrase;
    if(studentScore <= 150)
     phrase = 'line one<br>line two';
    else if(studentScore <= 300)
     phrase = 'line one<br>line two';
    else if(studentScore <= 450)
     phrase = 'line one<br>line two';
    else if(studentScore <= 600)
     phrase = 'line one<br>line two';
    else if(studentScore <= 800)
     phrase = 'line one<br>line two';
    else
     phrase = 'line one<br>line two';

      config = {
         elName: 'h2',
         text: phrase
      };

    courseSummary.appendChild(createElFromDef(config));
  }
```

**Does anyone have any further ideas?**

Comment: "Java" and "JavaScript" are two significantly different programming languages.

Comment: What do you mean by _"message from the IF is formatted onto several lines"_? Do you mean you need a message that will appear in html on multiple lines, or that you need code that will span multiple lines?

Comment: How do you render `phrase` to the page?

Comment: Hi Full code extract below

Comment: I don't think not being experienced and guessing around one problem to the next is a good way to do things. Take the 10-20h (maybe this weekend?) it needs for a basic understanding - read a full tutorial or short book. Afterwards solve these things easily.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestions so.

Comment: I do think not being experienced and guessing around one problem to the next is a good way to do things

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a bit of work the < \BR > route gave the best solution using the following code to control the message

```
var phraseDiv = document.createElement("p");
    phraseDiv.innerHTML = phrase;
    phraseDiv.setAttribute("style", "text-align: left;");
    courseSummary.appendChild(phraseDiv);
```

this is now outputting multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\n` as a literal newline character:

```js
console.log('one\ntwo');
```

Another option is to use template literals and use plain newlines, no escape character needed:

```js
console.log(`one
two`);
```

Or send an array and just `console.log` for each item in the array:

```js
const phrase = ["Well done, you have achieved level:", "triple platinum"];
phrase.forEach(line => console.log(line));
```

Also note that `var` is hoisted to the top of its function block. So, don't use `var` more than once for a particular variable name inside a function: only declare it once. Eg

```
var phrase;
if(studentScore <= 150)
  phrase = "Well done, you have achieved level bronze";
else if(studentScore <= 300)
  phrase = "Well done, you have achieved level silver";
```

Or, even better, keep your code DRY:

```js
function getPhrase(studentScore) {
  const levels = [
    [0, 'bronze'],
    [150, 'silver'],
    [300, 'gold'],
    [450, 'platinum'],
    [600, 'double platinum'],
    [800, 'triple platinum'],
  ].reverse();
  const str = levels.find(([score, str]) => studentScore > score)[1];
  return ['Well done, you have achieved level:', str];
}

const appendStr = str => str.forEach(line =>
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
    .textContent = line
);

appendStr(getPhrase(500));
appendStr(getPhrase(200));
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping your output with [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)  `${phrase}` is the best way to display a message with multiple lines

Answer (score 0):

Using `\n` or template strings will add newlines to the string in JavaScript, but they’ll be ignored by HTML. To make a newline in HTML use `<br>`.

```
phrase = 'hello<br>there'
```

Comment: Hi all just attempted the above but with no success does anyone have any more ideas. I have updated code above

Comment: You’ll also have to use `.innerHTML`, not `.innerText`, to write it to the document.